# Syntax error with if else in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying with following command to print specific columns based on if else condition as well as fields from nth column till last. This command does not give the correct output. It is throwing syntax error when tried like this. When tried each if else separately outside , it gives output but not in correct format.

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{if($1 != "NULL" && $2 != "NULL") print $3,$1,$4,$5,$2,$6;for (i = 7; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i); } printf("\n") ;
                                 else if($1 != "NULL" && $2 == "NULL") print $3,$1,$4,$5,$6,$7;for (i = 8; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s ", $i); } printf("\n");}'
```

Comment: Have you reviewed your own question before clicking the `send` button? Or do you think your question looks good?

Comment: You need to add a sample of your input and the corresponding desired output, so that we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited with correct answer

I have written below in a more easily readable way, so you can see where brackets should start and end. Feel free to put it all on one line though.

```
awk '{
          if($1 != "NULL" && $2 != "NULL"){
              printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $3,$4,$1,$5,$6,$2,$7)
              for (i = 7; i <= NF; i++){ 
                        printf("%s ", $i)
              }
              printf("\n")
          }
          else if($1 != "NULL" && $2 == "NULL"){ 
              printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", $3,$4,$1,$5,$6,$7,$8)
              for (i = 8; i <= NF; i++){ 
                  printf("%s ", $i)
              }
              printf("\n")
          }
      }' file
```